# What LayoutParams should be used in an AlertDialog?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, dialog

I have a `EditText` object:

```
    EditText textbox = new EditText (this);
    textbox.setHint (something);
```

I want to add this view to an `AlertDialog` using the builder.

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder (this);
    builder.setTitle (R.string.enter_password_name)
            .setPositiveButton (R.string.save_text, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener () {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton (R.string.cancel_text, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener () {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });
```

I know that there is a method `setView(int)` but I am using API 15 so I can only use `setView(View)`, which is also a reason why I am creating the view by code.

So far so good, but I now need to set the `LayoutParams` of the view. What `LayoutParams` should I choose? I know that in a `RelativeLayout` you use a `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` and in a `LinearLayout` you use a `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`. But what should I use in a dialog?

Comment: you dont need to create the layout programatically to use setView you know right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/alert_dialog.xml) , alertdialog's root element is a `LinearLayout`, so I would suggest using `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`

Comment: It now uses `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`

Answer (score 0):

Even if you want to `setView` with `view` as a parameter you can always create your view in xml and inflate it using a layout inflator and then use it as a parameter.

example:

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null);
setView(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you inflate a custom view or not.

- If you do that, you should use the LayoutParams according the
  custom view container (Linear or relative).
- If you don't use a custom view you
  can set Linear LayoutParams.